# JMS Serializer many to one relation, field on same level of main entity

Tags: symfony, jmsserializerbundle

I have an entity with a manyToOne relation, I want to serialize this entity with JMS serializer on Symfony.
But I want the related entity on the same level of the main entity, like if fields are just complementary fields of my main entity.

I have this :

```
"parcel_movement_action_button": {
  "code": "string",
  "type": "string"
},
"button_class": "string",
"value": "string"
```

I want this :

```
  "code": "string",
  "type": "string",
  "button_class": "string",
  "value": "string"
```

Is it possible ?

Answer (score 2):

Yes it's possible, you must use virtual property to do that https://jmsyst.com/libs/serializer/master/reference/annotations#virtualproperty

Comment: Thank you for your answer, that was exactly what i need !